# Identify if files or directories are hidden

Tags: bash, filenames

I am trying to write a bash script that prints out all files (including hidden) in a directory recursively and records the number of files, hidden files, hidden directories and directories. This is part of an assignment and I am not allowed to use `-R` or `find` or `du`.

```
listAllFiles() 
 {
  local dir=$1
  local file
  directoryCounter=0
  fileCounter=0
  hiddenFileCounter=0
  hiddenDirectoryCounter=0

  for file in "$dir"/*; do
  if [[ -d $file ]]; then
      listAllFiles "$file"
      directoryCounter+=1
  elif [[ -f $file ]];then
      fileCounter+=1]
      ls -l $file
  elif [[file is a hidden directory]];then
      listAllFile "$file"
      hiddenDirectoryCounter+=1
  elif [[file is a hidden file]];then
      hiddenFileCounter+=1
      ls -l $file
  fi
     done
 }
```

Is there a way I can detect if a file/directory is hidden

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hidden files and directories have names starting with `.`, so you can use the following solution in Bash:

```
# Skip '.' and '..':
if [ "$file_name" = . ] || [ "$file_name" = .. ];then
    continue
fi
# Find hidden files:
if [[ "$file_name" =~ ^\. ]];then # if file name starts with a .
...
```

Comment: hello, can this check "current directory" or "parent directory".

Comment: @JungsuHeo Good point, I added provisions for this in the answer.

Comment: IIRC `..X` and `...` are valid file/dir-names, would they not be handled in the same way as `..` by your regex

Comment: @Anthon You're right. A regex to handle such cases would probably be too complicated for Bash to interpret, though.

Comment: @JosephR. If necessary I would match everything starting with '.' and exclude the two exceptions '.' and '..' in a separate if statement. Even if I can get a complex regular expression to work, I never can read them back/understand them 10 minutes after I wrote them anyway.

Comment: +1 I agree with Anthon: you're doing this in a loop, so check specifically for `.` and `..` first; if one of those matches start the loop again.  If not, then match against `^\.`.

Comment: @goldilocks Thanks for providing the simplest way around it. Added to answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are no hidden files or directories on Unix native filesystems, at least not based on some attribute assigned in the metadata of the filesystem.

What is custom is that some commands like `ls`, do not, by default display file/directories where the name starts with a '`.`'. Other tools (like e.g. nautilus) follow this convention. If you look at the man page of `ls` it does not write about hidden files:

```
-a, --all
     do not ignore entries starting with .
```

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory#Unix_and_Unix-like_environments) this behavior is a result of a software bug in the early days of Unix.

Other tools, such as `find` will always display these files ignored by `ls`.

On Windows filesystems there are hidden files based on attributes, see e.g [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61423/how-can-i-change-the-hidden-attribute-of-a-file-folder-alternative-to-attrib-f) question.

I suspect that part of your homework is a trick question as people often mistake the hiding behaviour of `ls` with there being hidden files.

Comment: also, if one works with `ls` there is `--almost-all` (`-A`) which provides the same but without the `.` and `..` entries at the beginning of the listing

Comment: That was entirely my mistake, by hidden files I did mean a file starting with a **.**

Answer (score 0):

`find /directory_path -type f | wc -l` will give you the number of files

`find /directory_path -type d | wc -l` will give you the number of directories

Comment: a) This doesn't identify hidden files, b) "I am not allowed to use -R or find or du"

Comment: Ah...If `find` is not in use, then go with Joseph's solution. That will do the job

Comment: This does not work if the file names or directory names have newlines in them.

Comment: Well, it works here for Hidden files and file/directories containing space or newline character.  I am using Ubuntu-13.10 and findutils version is 4.4.2-6ubuntu1.   Anyway, since `find` will not be the solution for questioner then there is no point arguing/discussing about this command